Beamer - section numbering of appendix in toc when changed to Alph
My beamer document has an appendix consisting of multiple sections. I would like to have a slide that contains the toc of the main part of the document as well as the toc of the appendix. It should look like:
1. Section 1
2. Section 2
A. Appendix A
B. Appendix B
I've managed to reset the section counter so that after \appendix it starts with Section 1. I've also managed to change the section number formating to A, B,... by inserting \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} right after \appendix. This works fine when it comes to referencing the appendix sections but has no effect on the toc of the appendix, which looks like
1. Appendix A
2. Appendix B
How can I achieve that also in the toc appendix section numbers A. and B. appear insteaad of 1. and 2.?
MWE
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

% Reset the section counter to 0 when a new part begins
\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{%
    \beamer@tocsectionnumber=0\relax
    \setcounter{section}{0}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{TOC}
    \tableofcontents % toc of main part
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \tableofcontents[part=1] % toc of appendices
\end{frame}%

\section{Section 1}\label{sec:1}
\section{Section 2}\label{sec:2}
%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some frame}
    Some text of Section~\ref{sec:1}.\\
    Some text of Section~\ref{sec:2}.\\
    Some text of Appendix~\ref{sec:A}.\\
    Some text of Appendix~\ref{sec:B}.\\
\end{frame}%

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\section{Appendix A}\label{sec:A}
\section{Appendix B}\label{sec:B}
%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some frame}
\end{frame}%

\end{document}%


Quick hack: redefine the section in toc template before the second toc
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

% Reset the section counter to 0 when a new part begins
\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{%
    \beamer@tocsectionnumber=0\relax
    \setcounter{section}{0}
}

\newcommand{\quack}{
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{
      \leavevmode%
      % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
      \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
      \else
      \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
        \@Alph\inserttocsectionnumber.
      \fi\fi%
      \inserttocsection\par%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TOC}
    \tableofcontents % toc of main part
    \vspace{0.5em}
    
    \quack
    \tableofcontents[part=1] % toc of appendices
\end{frame}%

\section{Section 1}\label{sec:1}
\section{Section 2}\label{sec:2}
%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some frame}
    Some text of Section~\ref{sec:1}.\\
    Some text of Section~\ref{sec:2}.\\
    Some text of Appendix~\ref{sec:A}.\\
    Some text of Appendix~\ref{sec:B}.\\
\end{frame}%

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\section{Appendix A}\label{sec:A}
\section{Appendix B}\label{sec:B}
%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some frame}
\end{frame}%

\end{document}%



Thank you, works just fine.

@VK88 You're welcome!
